# How to use another scoring metric for HistGradientBoostingRegressor in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using `HistGradientBoostingRegressor` for some task and I want to use AUC as a scoring metric, instead of the default one.

My code is this:

```
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)
HG = HistGradientBoostingRegressor(learning_rate=0.001, max_iter=1000, scoring='auc')
HG.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Score: ', HG.score(X_val, y_val))
```

However, when running this code, the `score` method keeps displaying the old scores, instead of the new ones.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you display your output when running this on your data? I think I can help, but I need that information.

Comment: Like all sklearn models, the `score` method doesn't work to produce any other metrics.  Just make the predictions (probabilities in this case) and call the `roc_auc_score` metric directly.

Comment: Note that the `scoring` parameter mentions specifically that it is used for early stopping.

Comment: Yes that would help, I’ll take a look and advise @BogdanDoicin